# Deploy/publish more than one .NET core console application

Tags: .net-core, deployment, build, console-application

We have a number of .NET core console applications all sharing some small internal libraries. We would like to publish them as a single bundle with all internal libraries to a single XCOPYable folder. Microsoft currently has no solution for this (see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/publishing-multiple-net-core-applications-in-a-sin/1152838). I am wondering if someone has a pointer to how we might be able achieve this until there is a solution from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a PowerShell script that

1. built the apps
2. recursively copied all the publishable contents to a temporary staging folder
3. compressed the staging folder for deployment
4. deleted the staging folder
5. cleaned up build

Solves my problem. But if there is a better way out there, please let me know.